# How to avoid submitting form without value?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm sending some data from a form to a PHP script with AJAX with this code below. I need a quick answer I'm running out of time, I need a very quick and straight to the point way of not making the data send if the input of the form="", which means if the user just clicks save on a blank form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".ajaxcourse1").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "course1.php", 
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#editcourse1").html(
          data["course1"] 
        );


  }
});
return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you tryied a `if(data) { /* ajax */ } else { /* notice user */ }` ?? And you should be aware of attribute [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) for all input.

Comment: First, you can use required to your html form to some fields.

    <input type="text" required="">

Comment: var serialized = $(yourform).serialize();

    if(serialized.indexOf('=&') > -1 || serialized.substr(serialized.length - 1) == '='){
       //you've got empty values
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the form first. Wether you use a validation library like [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) or do it by hand by checking that the fields in the form are not empty/invalid.

```
$(".ajaxcourse1").submit(function(){
    var form_validates = $('.ajaxcourse1').parsley().isValid();

    if(!form_validates) { return false } // this will stop the form from sending your ajax call. 

    ... your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#whateveryourinputidis').val()) {
   // send data  
   $.ajax(parameters);
} else {
   // don't send data, perhaps alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are submitting the form by clicking a button, in this case you need to check the values before form submission and prevent it if there are empty fields:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" />

$(':submit').click(function(e) {
    if ($("#some_field").val().length == 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
     }else{
       //ajax call
     }
});
```

Comment: is there a simple way to use required on mobile? It works on pc but having issues on mobile

Comment: if you are using html5 you can use required fields : <input type="text" name="usrname" required>

Comment: required doesn't work on mobile! Though yes, I'm using html5

Comment: BTW, a form can be submited without clicking any `:submit` control

Answer (score 0):

can try this

```
var error = false;
$(this).find('input').each(function(key, value){ //this -> your form
   if(!value)
      error = true;
});
if(error)
   alert('Input data missing baby !!'); // or your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$(".ajaxcourse1").submit(function(e){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };

    var flag = true; 
    // validate your inputs here, 
    // this is just a sample validation

    $(this).find("input").each(function (i, row){
        if($(row).val() == ""){
           flag = false;
        }
    }); 

    if(flag === false){
       return false; // to cancel the form submit
    }else{

       data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/course1.php", 
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#editcourse1").html(
            data["course1"] 
          );
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.warn(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
          console.log('request has been completed, either it succeeded or it failed.)
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Guys all of your pieces of code worked in the part of not sending the font when submitted when empty, but the success part would never be reached, thus the form would not be submitted when not empty! Could you please post a complete working piece of code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check the values yourself when the form is submitted and aborting the submit if all values are not ok. But to fix this and also give you much more flexibility you could use the [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).